# What events are fired in the children of a TabView?

Tags: xaml, uwp, tabview

I have a `TabView` like this:

```
<TabView ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
    <TabView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <local:MyUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabView.ItemTemplate>
</TabView>
```

I've set an event handler for the `MyUserControl.Loaded` event just to see what happens. Surprisingly, **the event is only fired once**, regardless of which Tab is active. When you switch between tabs, the Loaded event isn't fired more than once

So, I tried to catch the Visibily changed event (using the `RegisterPropertyChangedCallback` method). It's never fired!

Then, I wonder if there's any event that is fired in MyCustomControl **whenever the active tab changes**, since the `Loaded` and "VisibilityChanged" events aren't being fired?

I need to send a message through a Message Bus whenever the TabView active contents change, but I need the MyUserControl be aware of the change, becuase it is the only one that knows what to send inside the message.

Comment: Check the "SelectionChanged"-Event => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tabview.selectionchanged?view=winui-2.2 I guess that's what you want. The Loaded-Event fires once the whole UI-Element is fully loaded...

Comment: Doesn't TabView have a SelectedItem you can bind to? Then you can invoke any methods in your SelectedItem Document whenever it changes.

Comment: OK, the problem with the SelectItem event is that it is fired before the Loaded event of the children is fired. Moreover, as I said, I need to intercept an event in the child being "activated" (the one whose contents are made visible on each tab switch) to send a message (using the Messenger pattern) that says "I have been activated". I finally got the answer via Twitter and I will post it here soon to illustrate it better.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to intercept an event in the child being "activated" (the one
>   whose contents are made visible on each tab switch)

You can use **`Tapped`** event for the `local:MyUserControl` then use `DataContext` to read which item is now tapped.  Tapped will trigger right before loading all the events. So this will help you in Intercepting Child being activated.